# Docker Unable to Startup due to error during gid lookup

Tags: linux, docker, group

I am having trouble getting docker to start on my virtual linux system.
When I enter the following command: `sudo dockerd`
I get: `Error during gid lookup for "john": getent unable to find entry "john" in group database` 
I am guessing I have something misconfigured in one of the group files.

When I use the command `cat group` in the /etc directory, I get the following: (I feel like there may be something wrong with my docker group at the very end)

```
root:x:0:
daemon:x:1:
bin:x:2:
sys:x:3:
adm:x:4:syslog
tty:x:5:syslog
disk:x:6:
lp:x:7:
mail:x:8:
news:x:9:
uucp:x:10:
man:x:12:
proxy:x:13:
kmem:x:15:
dialout:x:20:
fax:x:21:
voice:x:22:
cdrom:x:24:
floppy:x:25:
tape:x:26:
sudo:x:27:
audio:x:29:
dip:x:30:
www-data:x:33:
backup:x:34:
operator:x:37:
list:x:38:
irc:x:39:
src:x:40:
gnats:x:41:
shadow:x:42:
utmp:x:43:
video:x:44:
sasl:x:45:
plugdev:x:46:
staff:x:50:
games:x:60:
users:x:100:
nogroup:x:65534:
systemd-journal:x:101:
systemd-network:x:102:
systemd-resolve:x:103:
systemd-timesync:x:104:
crontab:x:105:
messagebus:x:106:
input:x:107:
kvm:x:108:
render:x:109:
syslog:x:110:
uuidd:x:111:
tcpdump:x:112:
ssh:x:113:
systemd-coredump:x:999:
docker:x:998:john
```

This is what comes up with the `cat subgid` command in the /etc directory:

```
john::
john:100000:65536
```

This is what comes up with the `cat subuid` command in the /etc directory:

```
john:1000:65536
```

Anything else you think you'd need to help troubleshooting or any things to try, please let me know. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like group "john" is missing in /etc/group. Add it with `sudo groupadd john`.